# Issue with Lightning Dashboard formula

Tags: lightning, reporting, formula, validation, dashboard

I have a report which is grouped using a custom field called Type__c. It holds two values, RN and NB. Now, I have created a formula in the lightning report to get the percentage of each record count.

Below is the formula:

```
RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, GRAND_SUMMARY)
```

Now, when i tried to use this report as a dashboard component with Number/Metric chart as widget, I am getting following error.

> To plot this summary formula, select Policy_log__c.Type__c

I didnt find any option to select the field in the dashboard properties and I want to display the percentages in dashboard based on Type__c filter. If NB is selected, it should display the percentage as 60% and if RN is selected, the value should be displayed as 40%.

Can anyone please suggest any changes so that i can get this done!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the Metric chart type with the report percentage formula like you're trying

As an alternative, you might want to consider using a Gauge chart type with a measure value of the Record Count, showing the Percentages but hiding the Values (and maybe the Range if you don't want it to show)

[image: Gauge Chart]

The dashboard filter will adjust the values in this chart like you're hoping it will for the NB and RN filter values